# What can I do with ! (exclamation point) when using Read-Host?

Tags: powershell

Let's start with the normal behavior. When I execute `Read-Host` without a prompt, I can enter a string starting with an exclamation point:

```
PS C:\> Read-Host | Foreach-Object { Write-Host 'Entered' $_ }
!hi, mom
Entered !hi, mom
```

(Note that I only pipe to `Foreach-Object` as an easy way to prefix the output. The behavior of interest is the same if you execute `Read-Host` without it.)

But if I give `Read-Host` a prompt argument, the behavior is quite different:

```
PS C:\> Read-Host 'Enter something' | Foreach-Object { Write-Host 'Entered' $_ }
Enter something: !hi, mom
"!hi, mom" cannot be recognized as a valid Prompt command.
Enter something: !!hi, mom
Entered !hi, mom
```

It seems the exclamation allows me to do some things besides just type in a string. PowerShell is interpreting the exclamation to mean I am entering some sort of command for it to run, but I can't find any documentation on what is allowed. Aside from doubling the exclamation to escape it, I can't figure out what *is* a valid command, either.

Note that the input has to *begin* with an exclamation point. Ending with it doesn't trigger this behavior:

```
PS C:\> Read-Host 'Enter something' | Foreach-Object { Write-Host 'Entered' $_ }
Enter something: hi, mom!
Entered hi, mom!
```

So what can I do with `!` here? What *is* a valid command, besides just escaping the exclamation? A work around is useful, but I'm actually wondering if I can execute code or something here.

I'm using PowerShell 4, but this seems to [date back](http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.aspx?G=10&ArtID=266474) to much earlier.

Comment: Further in that post that your link referenced (not shown in your link) Bruce Payette actually [posts](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/15221-bug-read-host-xxx-cant-read-xxx-2.html#post65011) a more useful response showing an example with somewhat more practical usage info.

Comment: Tangentially related: a simper way to prefix the output would be to use`"Entered: $(Read-Host)"` and `"Entered: $(Read-Host 'Enter Something')"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JetBrains dotPeek I found the implementation for where '!' is handled. It is in `Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHostUserInterface.PromptCommandMode` in the assembly `Microsoft.Powershell.ConsoleHost`. This is PS 3.0. The disassembled code is below.

The check for `strA.StartsWith` must be to see if the '!' is escaped with another '!'.

Note the check for `strA[0] == 63` is a check for '?' (0x3F). Any other single char input yields the error message in the OP. Two double quotes yields the empty string (which is what Bruce Payette said in the link referenced in the OP comments) and the string `'$null'` yields `$null`.

Anything else gives the same error message. So, short of some kind of proxying, or writing your Host, the '!' can't really be leveraged for other commands.

```
private string PromptCommandMode(string input, FieldDescription desc, out bool inputDone)
{
  string strA = input.Substring(1);
  inputDone = true;
  if (strA.StartsWith("!", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    return strA;
  if (strA.Length == 1)
  {
    if ((int) strA[0] == 63)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc.HelpMessage))
      {
        string str = StringUtil.Format(ConsoleHostUserInterfaceStrings.PromptNoHelpAvailableErrorTemplate, (object) desc.Name);
        ConsoleHostUserInterface.tracer.TraceWarning(str);
        this.WriteLineToConsole(this.WrapToCurrentWindowWidth(str));
      }
      else
        this.WriteLineToConsole(this.WrapToCurrentWindowWidth(desc.HelpMessage));
    }
    else
      this.ReportUnrecognizedPromptCommand(input);
    inputDone = false;
    return (string) null;
  }
  if (strA.Length == 2 && string.Compare(strA, "\"\"", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
    return string.Empty;
  if (string.Compare(strA, "$null", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
    return (string) null;
  this.ReportUnrecognizedPromptCommand(input);
  inputDone = false;
  return (string) null;
}

private void ReportUnrecognizedPromptCommand(string command)
{
  this.WriteLineToConsole(this.WrapToCurrentWindowWidth(StringUtil.Format(ConsoleHostUserInterfaceStrings.PromptUnrecognizedCommandErrorTemplate, (object) command)));
}
```

Comment: Found the [source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHostUserInterfacePrompt.cs#L479).

Answer (score 7):

**tl;dr**

- `Read-Host`, as the name suggests, is *host-specific*.

  - As of PSv5.1, the ***standard console* host** (console windows) and, **in PSv3+, the ISE too** exhibit the unexpected behavior. (In PSv2-, the ISE used its own GUI `Read-Host` prompt, which wasn't affected).
- The behavior is in effect **an *unrelated* feature that is seemingly accidentally exposed**, namely ***only* if `Read-Host`'s prompt-string parameter (`-Prompt`) is specified.**

  - Given that the behavior is **undocumented** and **exposed in this obscure manner**, it should be considered a **bug**.
- **Work around the bug** as follows:

  - `Write-Host -NoNewline 'Enter something: '; Read-Host`
  - I.e.: Use `Write-Host` to print the prompt string separately, *beforehand* (without a line break), then invoke `Read-Host` *without* the `-Prompt` parameter:

To answer the question's title, "What can I do with ! when using Read-Host?": Nothing useful.
To see why, and for background information, read on.

---

The behavior - and complaints about it - dates back to the very first version of PowerShell; in the [post also linked to by the OP](http://www.devsuperpage.com/search/Articles.aspx?G=10&ArtID=266474) an MS employee calls it a **"Prompt command"**, and one of its architects explains it in more detail [here](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/15221-bug-read-host-xxx-cant-read-xxx-2.html#post65011)<sup>discovered by @TheMadTechnician in a comment on the question</sup>.
Note that is is **discussed in the context of how PowerShell *itself* prompts for *missing mandatory parameter values***, which really ***should* have *no* relationship with `Read-Host`**:

When prompted for a mandatory parameter value that wasn't specified on the command line (and unexpectedly also when using `Read-Host` with a `-Prompt` value), `!` as the *very first* character (only) starts a "prompt command":

- `!?` invokes the help string for (the description of) the parameter at hand.

  - In the context of `Read-Host`, the prompt string(!) is interpreted as the parameter name whose help is sought, and consequently no help is found (`No help is available for <prompt-string>`).
- `!""` allows entering an empty string as a parameter value for an *array* parameter while allowing entry of additional values (just pressing Enter would instantly *terminate* the prompt).

  - In the context of `Read-Host`, this simply outputs an empty string.
- `!!` allows entering a *literal* `!`
- [Χpẘ's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35496059/45375) uses disassembly of the underlying assemblies to show that, at least as of PS v3, no additional commands are supported.

The [linked forum post](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/15221-bug-read-host-xxx-cant-read-xxx-2.html#post65011) concludes (emphasis mine):

> Note that this is an **artifact of the current implementation of
>   prompting in the PowerShell host**. It's not part of the core engine. A
>   **GUI host would be unlikely to use this notation**. A **reasonable
>   enhancement would be to allow the prompt command to be
>   user-configurable**.

10 years later, the behavior - at least in the context of `Read-Host` - is neither documented nor configurable.

Before the above post was discovered, [jpmc26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394393/jpmc26) had himself found that the behavior is related to how PowerShell *itself* prompts for *missing mandatory arguments*; e.g.:

```
# Define a test function with a mandatory parameter.
> function foo([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage='fooParam help')][string]$fooParam) {}

# Invoke the test function *without* that mandatory parameter,
# which causes Powershell to *prompt* for it.
> foo
cmdlet foo at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
fooParam: !?   # !? asks for help on the parameter, which prints the HelpMessage attribute.
fooParam help
fooParam:      # After having printed parameter help, the prompt is shown again.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another piece of the puzzle.
I'm running V5, and it works in the ISE:

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable


Name                           Value                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                  
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.51                                                                                           
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.51                                                                                          
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209                                                                                        
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                    
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                    
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1       

PS C:\> Read-Host 'Enter something' | Foreach-Object { Write-Host 'Entered' $_}
Enter something: !Hi, mom
Entered !Hi, mom
```

But it doesn't work from a normal command prompt:

```
PS C:\> Read-Host 'Enter something' | Foreach-Object { Write-Host "Entered $_"}
Enter something: !Hi, mom
"!Hi, mom" cannot be recognized as a valid Prompt command.
Enter something:
```

Comment: The problem is unrelated to `Write-Host`. Simply try `Read-Host 'Enter something'`, then enter `!`, and see what happens. Aside from that, `Write-Host` _does_ write _both_ arguments to the host, which you can verify as follows: `Write-Host one two | Out-Null` - both arguments are still echoed.

Comment: The `Write-Host` works correctly, as you can see in the example output. If you pass multiple arguments to `Write-Host`, it prints them all with a space inbetween.

Comment: If it's unrelated to Write-Host, then the posted solution should exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: It does. I copy/pasted your command into my prompt, and I get the same behavior. In fact, you get this behavior without the `Foreach` part at all. I just used that so I could prefix the output.

Comment: Then I'll withdraw the answer.  I'm running V5 and it works fine.

Comment: I think the fact it behaves differently in V5 is an answer worth posting. If you'll edit and warn not to rely on the behavior (or indicate that there's another way to reproduce it), I'll gladly upvote.

Comment: @mklement0 - Updated the answer.  It works from the ISE, but it doesn't work from a normal command prompt.  Looks buggy as hell.

Comment: Indeed, that's the difference - it depends on the _host_ - and, I suspect, the host _only_: v3 exhibits the same difference (fine in the ISE, broken in a console window). And, yes, it smells like a bug.